# django Procfile for heroku deployment using gunicorn

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

According to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format) documentation, the `Procfile` format is

```
<process type>: <command>
```

For example:

```
web: gunicorn djforms.wsgi --log-file -
```

However, I found a Django project where the Procfile was missing `:` after `web`. i.e.

```
web gunicorn djforms.wsgi --log-file -
```

It also worked correctly when I tried to deploy to `heroku`. Any Idea on why it works or issues it may cause? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the second example worked. Unlike [for Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type), as far as I know Heroku doesn't have a fall-back default command for Python applications. And if a malformed `Procfile` were in the right place, Heroku should complain about its format.

Comment: The second example worked for me. I tried it again with a new Django project. It deployed successfully with no errors.